# Access Salesforce logs externally

Tags: logging

I would like to know if its possible to access Salesforce logs externally. We have requirement where different system interact with Salesforce and if there is any failure in between then we raise automated IT Ticket and IT people needs log information to diagnose the problem. IT people don't have access to Salesforce.

One solution I could think of is to use Elk Logging tool but not sure if they already have an integration or app with SFDC.

Answer (score 0):

There is an object called **ApexLog**, which should have what you seek (not sure if it contains details).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm

You can provide you credentials for them to pull it, or write a trigger to post to IT's webservice via Outbound Messaging.

Comment: Thanks James and I am sure I can call ApexLog with webservice metadata api.